# Separable closure of $p$-adic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Is the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ a perfect field? What is its separable closure in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is characteristic 0, so it's trivially perfect...

Comment: I believe that the separable closure of a field is an extension, namely the subset of the (properly, *an*) algebraic closure consisting of all elements that are separable over the given field.